# React re-rendering every cell of the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a really big rerender problem in every cell of the table because of the handleClick function even used useCallback.

My cell component like; (wrapped with React.memo())

```
<StyledTableCell onContextMenu={() => handleClick()} style={{ backgroundColor: `${(flash && data) ? 'yellow' : color}`, transition: `${flash ? 'none' : '1s'}` }}>
    <div className='cell-size' >
      {data}
    </div>
  </StyledTableCell >

export const MemoizedDataCell = React.memo(DataCell)
```

and this cell goes to the upper level like ;

```
<MemoizedDataCell handleClick={() => onCellClick(selectedOrders, i, Boolean(val))} data={val} key={colName + i} color={cellColor(i, z)} />
```

And finally, in the top parent, I use this function for the child ;

```
  const onCellClick = React.useCallback((myOrder: any, i: number, isFilled: boolean) => {

    setCanDeal(isFilled)
    let side = i < 3 ? 'bids' : 'asks'
    console.log(myOrder)
    if (i < 0) {
      return null
    }
    if (!myOrder.asks && !myOrder.bids) {
      const detail = {
        instrName: myOrder.instName, maturity: myOrder.maturity, side: side.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + side.slice(1, -1), contract: `${myOrder.instName} ${myOrder.maturity}`,
        price: '0', quantity: '0', totalQuantity: '0', tradableQuantity: '0'
      }
      return setOrderDetail(detail)
    }

    let orderID = myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.OrderID
    let instrName = myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.InstName
    let maturity = myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.FirstSequenceItemName
    let contract = `${instrName} ${maturity}`
    let broker = myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.Broker
    let price = myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.Price
    let quantity = myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.Volume
    let timeInForce = myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.OrderType.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim()
    let lastUpdTime = new Date(myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.DateTime).toLocaleString()
    let tradableQ = '-'
    let totalQ = '-'
    let priceStat = myOrder[`${side}`][0]?.Status
    side = side.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + side.slice(1, -1)

    const detail = {
      orderID: orderID, instrName: instrName, maturity: maturity, side: side, contract: contract,
      price: price, priceStatus: priceStat,
      quantity: quantity, totalQuantity: totalQ,
      tradableQuantity: tradableQ, broker: broker, lastUpdate: lastUpdTime, timeInForce: timeInForce
    }
    setOrderDetail(detail)
  }, [])
```

Any help ll be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you memoizing your `Cell` ?
If you use `memo` or `useMemo`, it does a `===` comparison with each previous props

And as you're doing:

```js
<MemoizedDataCell handleClick={() => onCellClick(selectedOrders, i, Boolean(val))} .. />
```

You are creating a new function at each render for `handleClick`, so `MemoizedDataCell` will be re-rendered.

So you need to memoize this function

```js
const _handleClick = useCallback(() => onCellClick(...), []) // With good values in dependency array

<MemoizedDataCell handleClick ={_handleClick} />
```

This way, you're passing as prop the same function reference at each render

Also note that doing something like:

```js
<Component style={{ backgroundColor: ... }} />
```

Will also re-renders every time as you are creating a new `Object` each time

Comment: thanks a lot! but I need those 3 parameters and they can change from line to line due to different cell typesand when i memoized there my function broken and not showing the values.

Comment: its because of the empty dependency array as you said but i really cant realize what i am supposed to put inside